# Reputation from Documentation links shown differently in iOS app

Tags: discussion, ios-app

iOS 10.3, App version 1.6.4

In the feed view "Earlier Today" section, rep gained from links to Documentation topics I've edited appear as links to the questions/answers where the topic is referenced.

[image]

I don't recall ever having seen this before, and it led to some head-scratching since I'm not in any way associated with those questions or any of their answers.  It took a few minutes to figure out why I was getting the rep.

In the Achievements page and in the web UI, these links don't appear and the the rep is shown as just "Arrays"

[image]

I suppose it *could* be useful to see the question/answer where the Doc topic is linked.

Is this working as intended?  Should it work this way or just mirror the Achievements view.

[IMHO it's excessive that every link to a Doc topic that I somehow touched at some point in distant memory gives me rep, but that's for another discussion.]